Discover an ONVIF IP Camera Running on Different Network
I have a Dahua bodycam, that supports onvif protocol. I have an option to register the camera to an platform IP.
I have a machine running on AWS that i want to run a discovery onvif server. My question is: if i register my bodycam to my public aws ip, should it work?
I tried to run this python code to discover it, but i couldn't discover the camera.
from wsdiscovery.discovery import ThreadedWSDiscovery as WSDiscovery
from wsdiscovery.publishing import ThreadedWSPublishing as WSPublishing
from wsdiscovery import QName, Scope

# Define type, scope & address of service
ttype1 = QName("https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl", "Device")
scope1 = Scope("onvif://www.onvif.org/Profile")
xAddr1 = "192.168.1.127:8080"

# Publish the service
wsp = WSPublishing()
wsp.start()
wsp.publishService(types=[ttype1], scopes=[scope1], xAddrs=[xAddr1])

# Discover it (along with any other service out there)
wsd = WSDiscovery()
wsd.start()
services = wsd.searchServices()
for service in services:
    print(service.getEPR() + ":" + service.getXAddrs()[0])
wsd.stop()

